# @posedge clk not working

Tags: verilog, clock

I am learning Verilog and I am implementing a half adder that should change its output only when the positive edge of clock comes, but the result changes with input, not with the clock.

Here is code of the program:

```
module Full_adder_clk_chng(
  input a,b, clk,
  output sum,cout
);
reg sum,cout;
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  assign cout= a&b;
  assign sum=a ^b;
end
endmodule
```

And here is testbench code:

```
module tb2;

// Inputs
reg a;
reg b;
reg clk;

// Outputs
wire sum;
wire cout;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
Full_adder_clk_chng uut (
    .a(a), 
    .b(b), 
    .clk(clk), 
    .sum(sum), 
    .cout(cout)
);

initial begin
clk=0;
end
always begin
#5; clk=~clk;
end
initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    #20;

    a=1;
    b=0;
    #23;

    a=0;
    b=0;
    #25;

    a=1;
    b=1;
    #3;

    a=0;
    b=0;
    #1;

    a=1;
    b=1;
    #1;

    a=0;
    b=0;
    #1;

    a=1;
    b=1;
    #20;
    $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `assign` keyword created continuous assignment. If placed in an procedural code (such as an always block) the continuous assignment starts when the procedural code executes. In this case a positive edge clock keeps re-initiating the continuous assignment.

It is a rare case when procedural `assign` is necessary. Acceding to the latest LRM procedural `assign`/`deassign` are being considered for deprecation citing it can be "inefficient, easily abused, and the source of design problems", [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § C.4 (note: IEEE merged Verilog & SystemVerilog in 2009).

To have `cout` and `sum` updated on each positive edge clock, simply omit the `assign`. Since this is synchronous logic, it is recommenced to use non-blocking assignment (`<=`). Combinational logic should use blocking assignment (`=`).

```
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  cout <= a&b;
  sum  <= a^b;
end
```